# Change default file icon adding graphical label or similar to it, using Qt library

Tags: qt, user-interface, icons

I want do something like this:

[image]

So, add label or graphical label to folders from Qt library, and I don't know what I have to do.

I think, firstly I have to get/take default icon for element and then I suppose, I have to add the label (or PNG) to the icon, or similar, and finally show both.

I'm doing a app similar to DropBox, and files inside a folder have this status label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is most likely system-specific. On Windows you would use the `desktop.ini` file and some system handler to display the icons. On Mac probably something else.

Comment: Umm, so, do you think that it is more specific to OS's ?, for example in windows, if I change desktop.ini, and change settings, I'' change icon whatever I want?

Comment: And, Linux, and Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point for creating it for Windows:

**Creating Shell Extension Handlers**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx

**How to Create Icon Handlers**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT: Another link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects

Hope that helps.

Comment: But with MacOSX , or Linux? a Cross-Plattform ?

Comment: Qt doesn't have it built in as far as I know.  I doubt Boost has it either.  If you make one that works for all three, you should contribute it to the Qt project.

Comment: Thanks, I saw "Icon Overlay", and I think, it is the only method to do it, but the problem with it is that I have to do distinct code for three plattforms.

Comment: Ok, not a unique solution, really I have to manage on distinct Os'es details to change this depends on where app be running. In Qt I'll find functions to Overlay, but is not well documented or not clear.